# First click will not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, hide, getelementsbytagname

The first click does not work but every click after does perfectly. Is there anything I'm doing wrong or is it the site? (I'm using JS Fiddle by the way)

```
$("a").click(function () {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    $(x).click(function () {
        var y = this.parentElement.parentElement;
        $(y).hide("slide", {
            direction: "right"
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: why is `$(x).click()` inside a `$("a").click()`.... also where is the fiddle

Comment: huh guess I didn't pick that up, that would actually make sense if i took one click away.

Comment: Here's the corrected fiddle if you'd like a look. https://jsfiddle.net/Grandmaster27971/rf8q4nz9/35/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1):

On your first click, you are executing a function that adds another click listener, so it won't be executed until it is clicked again. Try something like this:

```
function yourFunction() {
    var y = this.parentElement.parentElement; // this may have to be slightly modified - I'm not sure of the rest of your code
    $(y).hide("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    }, 1000);
}

$("a").click(function () {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    $(x).click(yourFunction);
    yourFunction(); // calling yourFunction here also ensures it's called on the first click
});
```

Edit: this is redundant. Arun P Johny has a much cleaner solution. This is what I get for staying up all night.

Answer (score 1):

In your code the first click will register another click handler which is actually doing the work so when the first click happens there is no handler which is actually hiding the parent element.

Also here you are attaching a new click handler in each click of the anchor element.

Instead you can just add the hide logic in the first click handler itself like

```
$("a").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().hide("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    }, 1000);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ee674d5b/)